# Named slots of svelte within a div - not the child of the component

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Let's say that I have 'Template.svelte' with the following named slots

```
<div class="template">
    <div><slot name="header"></slot></div>
    <div><slot name="body"></slot></div>
    <div><slot name="footer"></slot></div>
</div>
```

In another svelte file, I am accessing this component. But I need to accept the slots in the following manner

```
<Template>
   <div class="header_class">
       <div slot="header"></div>
   <div>
    
    <div class="footer_class">
        <div slot="footer"></div>
    </div>

</Template>
```

It throws an `Error` that:

```
Element with a slot='...' attribute must be a child of a component or a descendant of a custom elements.
```

Is there a method for rendering nested named slots in svelte?

Comment: The <svelte:fragment> element allows you to place content in a named slot without wrapping it in a container DOM element. This keeps the flow layout of your document intact.
https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-fragment

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? I.e. what would the end result of that be?

Comment: @H.B. My comment may have been vague about whether I want wrapper (I do specifically want wrappers) so rewriting it:

I am not OP but I have the same problem. I have a component with 3 slots, and I wish to wrap the first two slots in a div.

Comment: @mikemaccana: This doesn't make sense; you cannot "wrap" a slot, there is nothing to wrap. Just add the `slot="..."` on the outer div and you have multiple nested divs in the place of the slot.

Comment: I wanted the content that goes into the slots to get wrapped. I’m not sure why this’s doesn’t make sense. Imagine a div that contains two elements. Now imagine a div that contains two slots. In pseudocode: `[component [wrapper div [slot 1] [slot 2]] [slot 3]]`. I think this is similar to what the OP wanted.